# Buoy Antenna for long range wifi bridge over water

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, antenna

I would like to setup a wifi bridge from a LAN on shore to a Buoy in the ocean (1,3 or 5 miles away) which would be tethered to an ROV.
My question is what would be the best antenna and frequency to use for the Buoy factoring in that it will be rotating, bopping and rocking. I'm assuming an Omni would be best but don't know how well it performs if it is constantly moving. Also can I do it with the 5Ghz, or is it better to go to a lower frequency.

Thanks

Comment: Lower the frequency the less the signal drop is over distance. This will be a difficult project to complete. This distance would require a focused antenna for WIFI, which is a problem with the antenna constantly moving. What exactly are you trying to do with the data out there? You may be able to go with an Arduino solution, but the data on the long range transceivers for these is usually limited to serial rates. (9600 baud) but would work well for digital sensors.

Comment: You may want to ask this question over at the hardware recommendations community.